# How to make C# check for which numbers are entered by the user?

Tags: c#

I'm making a where the users enters as many numbers as they want,so long as they're between 1 and 10, then once they're done the program lists the number they entered and how many times. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2S31.png)

Now my question is how would you make C# read and check which numbers they entered and print them out and how many times they entered it like in the bottom of the picture? Sorry for the noob question i'm new to this language.

Here is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_3
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Exercise1()
        {
            //int min;
            //int max;
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter minimum integer: ");
            //min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter maximum integer: ");
            //max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //int start = min;
        }

        static void Exercise2()
        {
            string entry;
            Console.Write("Enter an integer or 'q' to quit ");
            entry = Console.ReadLine();
            while (entry.ToLower() != "q")
            {
                int number;
                if (int.TryParse(entry, out number))
                {
                    if (number >= 1 && number <= 10)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your number must be between 1 and 10");
                    }
                }
                Console.Write("Enter an integer or 'q' to quit ");
                entry = Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Exercise1();

            Exercise2();

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to end");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to store the numbers in a data structure, something like a List.  C# provides you with many collections to work with, such as `List<int>`.

Comment: Then you could use .Distinct() to display a list of numbers entered and you can use .GroupBy() to find the number of occurences of each number.  This smells like a school project, so please try to solve it on your own :-)

Comment: this is decent looking code, so I imagine it's a homework problem handed to you.  Tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: This is what I have so far. This is my code but I have hit the end of my knowledge and have had trouble trying to figure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we do not do your homework, so I will just point you around in the documentation with enough information you are not lost.

Use a Dictionary to keep the nnumber and counter. This is easiest - if a number is entered, get the counter, add one, put back into dictionary. If not - set 1 as value for the number.

At the end you go throuch all the keys (that are the numbers) and print the corresponding values (the number of times).

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed. I wasn't asking for you guys to do my homework. I just have hit a dead end because this is far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: Appreciated - also that you go onto this with the right attitude. In the beginning programming is super confusing for anything except the super trivial super small stuff. What we do not like is people with the attitude they learn by getting things made by others ;) So, congratulations - you are one step ahead and on your way to understand things.